# Change Property from a base class to [NonSerialized]

Tags: c#, serialization

So I have a base class and there a property that is set to be [Serializable].
In the derived class I would like to make that property [NonSerialized].

How can this be done?

Comment: If it's a non-virtual property, you can just hide the base property (using `new`) and add `NonSerialized` attribute in the derived class.

Comment: hmmm tried that...doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: In what way did it not work?  Also, which type of Formatter are you using to serialize your derived object?

Comment: I'm not sure what formatter I am using, the defualt JSON formatter for WCF.

Comment: Assuming you mean the DataContractJsonSerializer, it seems to work for me - at least for a simple test case and my definition of "work".  The derived class's NonSerialized field is not serialised (and so is zero after the round-trip), the hidden base class field _is_ serialised and so has the same value before and after the round-trip.  Of course I just called WriteObject and ReadObject on a MemoryStream so I didn't really _use_ WCF and the class I serialised only has one int field so it isn't terribly complex.

Comment: can you post your sample, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a violation of OOP. The base class has established the fact that this property is serializable. It must be possible to substitute any instance of a derived class for an instance of the base class. This means that every instance of the derived class must have that property serializable.

Comment: is there any way to change this on the base class at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot substitute a new attribute, but you can define a property called `ShouldSerializePropertyName` (where `PropertyName` is the name of your property) that always returns `false`. This should override the presence of the attribute on the property.

For example,

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [Serialized]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public bool ShouldSerializeMyProperty { get { return false; } }
}
```